# Encryption in JS and Decryption in PHP (RSA)

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, rsa

I use the library "JSEncrypt" for JS

HTML & JS & AJAX to PHP (send encrypted text to php file for decryted)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RSA js - php</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://passport.cnblogs.com/scripts/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
const servPubKeyPem = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\
MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEApa35WYXLyAIoIikbTU7J\
qQyltZX+zj8ea2bwCcs0rVcpSqMsYYWElQhvGXwSG1Dnd1jY3kNoqOvxb0oRToPj\
wLtx4xLh/RrH5eb9Xhssmo+KYhHFPu/FDBeAy4RQyP/Rv4CIIjWscj3aCiBDPrrM\
S6olwPtCRPsszG4TuUe29pW60JNCnU/1o+7rfjOCecdJpvVvqRW2vN4yxgkjAsf6\
UYyrnd9NXCaElG7X3jYKX84PSBTfttIHUthu+u37FLFUoKOZwqO4Lv0OfacevFCJ\
T4OoMnibeiygSVu8y94MtODp2SMCJ2OteKz8/11uzU27T4x9odS/DrevBebY2V5I\
94cpjyHVzJvNxqrwQ7nNOk0Y7rPvLvKfIGXXD708LRqMNpYZwj9Wu4aOXaxC6myW\
lguGT+OX3TfFzQ1dLyslGTiuy9f41AOJiK+PUnTZh84UALtnSnS62bM39+OaWHZc\
xlI7lHDK8mYxgzp9Us6WvLRBH15j3sSNV+GWCLOIk8Y6UIV/RYMCUNdVahiVqOH8\
0vevhdGZQHTLKmNdaiqCOI9R0hZLbFLzkph/kNnFKRlI0MoYn8Tqg2BRIPFYizPf\
eK+y4nmvJhmiMq3ZzUmVApt2deufZIJmNfqmnDyMKOICnYxcH0zJCrKmBmlM9u1i\
PMIXYCIshW2D3E1ACCPOw3ECAwEAAQ==\
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
    encrypt.setPublicKey(servPubKeyPem);
    var encryptedText = encrypt.encrypt('Hello my friend!');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {'encryptedText' : encryptedText},
        success: function(data) {
            
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $encryptedText = $_POST['encryptedText'];

    $priKeyPem = file_get_contents('../php/priKey.pem');
    
    $priKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($priKeyPem); //PriKey - PrivateKey - (he is work) 
  openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedText, $decryptedText, $priKey);

    # but $decryptedText == null ...

?>
```

I need to encrypt the text in JS pass the encrypted text in PHP and in PHP decrypt it, but in PHP I get "null"... Please help :/

Comment: The keys are correct, if you encrypt the text in PHP and immediately decrypt it, then everything will turn out ...

Comment: openssl_error_ string() ;

Comment: data greater than mod len

Comment: Please post *complete* test data: public and *related* private key (not production keys), plaintext, ciphertext. In your current post the private key and the ciphertext are missing.

Comment: @Topaco, thanks, but i dont use base64_decode($encryptedText) - in PHP, its be a problem (AND SORRY FROM MY ENGLISH)